# border-radius not making image circular in Safari in div with padding and border

Tags: html, css, safari, webkit, sass

I have a `<div>` with an `img` inside.

Structured like:

```
<div class="gift">
    <img>
</div>
```

The `div` has this CSS:

```
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
width: auto;
vertical-align: middle;
position: relative;
border-radius: 50em;
```

The image has this CSS:

```
border: 1px solid 
rgba(46, 46, 46, 0.1);
border-radius: 50em;
padding: 3px;
min-height: 10em;
height: 10em;
```

In Safari, it looks like [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSaWK.png):

[image: Safari image clipped]

But, in Chrome it looks how it is supposed to [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEG7I.png):

[image: Chrome - image appears correctly]

Any suggestions on how to get the image to appear in Safari the same way it does in Chrome?

Comment: Try using border-radius: 50%;   (not em)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed by basically by give `img` this CSS:

```
img{
    border-radius: 50em;
    min-height: 10em;
    height: 10em;
    width: 10em;
    min-width: 10em;
}
```

And gave the `div` this CSS:

```
div.gift{
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 10em;
    height: 10em;
    width: 10em;
    min-width: 10em;
    border: 1px solid rgba(46, 46, 46, 0.1);
    padding: 3px;
    border-radius: 50em;
}
```

The border-radius value doesn't matter so long as it's bigger than the height and width values to get a cirlce.

Comment: You should use 50%  for border radius to get a circle. It always works regardless of the elements size.

Answer (score -2):

I overcome this issue by using rounded PNG images with rounded border and 50% of radius.